# Unable to search for users or contacts by email address

Tags: configuration, search, global-search

When I type in the email address of a contact and also of a user in the global search, it does not return any records for either contact or user although there are both a contact and user record with this email address. Is this a feature limitation in Salesforce or do I need to make config changes to enable this level of searching?

Comment: It works on my Developer Edition without any configuration ! What edition do you use ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your search is not being filtered by anything else. You can see that by clicking on **Options**, if you are using divisions, you need to be searching on all divisions or on the correct division. Notice the **"limit to items I own**" and "**Exact phrase**" filters.

[image]